# Magento not allowing responsive design?

Tags: magento, responsive-design

So earlier I was stumped on why my website becomes unreadable (this is my first theme I'm creating in Magento) when I scale the website down to a phone size or small tablet size using Resizer bookmarklet in Chrome. I've created multiple responsive designs and never had this problem.

I figured out it's because that this gets appended into the style attribute on the  tag:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0.6122448979591837); -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px; min-width: 980px;
```

How exactly do I find what's appending that to the html style attribute? I'm guessing that's just a thing magento does by default in one of the javascript files?

Because when I delete that off the style attribute on the html tag, the page loads fine with the font size readable and everything else like it originally would.

These are all the default js files that Magento loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clearchannel.halfoffdeals.com/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clearchannel.halfoffdeals.com/js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clearchannel.halfoffdeals.com/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clearchannel.halfoffdeals.com/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clearchannel.halfoffdeals.com/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clearchannel.halfoffdeals.com/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clearchannel.halfoffdeals.com/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clearchannel.halfoffdeals.com/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clearchannel.halfoffdeals.com/js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clearchannel.halfoffdeals.com/js/varien/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clearchannel.halfoffdeals.com/js/varien/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clearchannel.halfoffdeals.com/js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clearchannel.halfoffdeals.com/js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unlikely that Magento is doing anything. That looks like more something a jQuery (or a JS plugin) would do. Are you using any front-end libraries that scale or resize elements?

Comment: I'm using Resizer... but that wouldn't make sense because it works with my other designs and doesn't scale them down like that. I feel like it's one of the js files that Magento includes by default since their default template does it as well. Magento is the only CMS I had problems with for responsive designing while my custom made responsive design from bare html and css (only files I include) doesn't scale it down like this..

Comment: I designed giftimity.com. Just checked that website with Resizer bookmarklet and this is the only thing added to the style attribute on the html tag : background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); So it's not Resizer doing it.. Magento includes a LOT of random js files that I think might have something to do with it..

Comment: To what tag(s) is this CSS being applied? What version of Magento are you using? And are there any extensions installed? And are you using a boilerplate theme to work from?

Comment: I'm using the latest installation of Magento 1.7. Right on the main <html> tag, a style attribute is being appended with that css in it. Whereas my other custom made code, it doesn't alter the <html> tag so it has to be the Magento JS libraries that are loaded by default. There are no extensions installed. This is a brand new installation where I'm just developing a theme. I'm using the base theme that comes with every brand new installation (but got rid of the styles.css file that came by default).

Comment: Just edited my first post, with the JS files that Magento includes by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where this is coming from, but here's a tip. If you're working in Chrome, pull up the inspector (F12 on Windows).

Then, click the Elements tab (at upper-left). Right-click on the `<html>` node, and select `Break On ... > Attributes Modifications`. Then refresh your page.

If this is a JavaScript-driven problem, then the inspector **should** catch the change to the `HTML` element, and pause execution right at the line of the file which is adding these styles. That will tell you where the problem lies.

If it works, let me know and I can try to help further.

Comment: Hmm what the hell. :/ No nothing pops up. But Resizer is the one that is doing it. But when I go to giftimity.com and use my Resizer and go down to the same screen size as I am doing on the site I'm working on, nothing gets added to the html tag.. even though that stuff gets added onto the html tag of my magento theme. If I just manually resize the window, it looks fine, but when I use Resizer, it looks terrible.. :/ But on all my other custom hand written code sites, it looks fine..

Comment: Well I downloaded that extension to take it for a test drive. Something that I don't like about it, is that it manipulates the DOM of your page, and adds in its own stylesheet for simulating viewport sizes. Another problem with it I see is that it loads in jQuery if not found in memory from Google's CDN. If you know anything about jQuery and prototype, they share the `$` variable, and this Resizer script doesn't appear to account for that (I see no `jQuery.noConflict()` calls anywhere in its source). So that can create issues with Prototype JS. (continued ...)

Comment: So my best advice is to stop using Resizer for this project. If you're using Bootstrap, you don't need Resizer anyway, as Bootstrap's responsive stylesheet makes noticeable changes to your layout at the most common viewports anyway (tablet, desktop, phone)... so if you resize your browser manually, you'll easily see those changes.

Comment: ok thanks. the only reason i used that bookmarklet is because it uses the popular sizes so i know which media queries to output. i dont know the exact pixels for all those screen resolutions and that helped out a lot when styling with my css.

Comment: Gotcha. Well now that you're used to those resolutions, you have them memorized by now, right? :) I hope you do well on this project.